# Joining and Counting in the same query without double calculation of field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am joining some tables on a certain criteria. I would like to know if it's possible to also display the count of those records that were excluded from the join?

my query:

```
SELECT...

FROM         dbo.QuickLabDump 
             ...

             left outer join hermes.lom.dbo.lom_specimen Lom
              on QuickLabDump.[specimen id] = lom.specimen
              LEFT outer join SalesDWH.dbo.Isomers Isomers
              on QuickLabDump.[specimen id] = Isomers.[accession id]



WHERE     lom.specimen is null
              and isomers.[accession id] is null...
```

as you can see i have two left outer joins.

in addition to the results of this query, i also want to return the count of those records from `hermes.lom.dbo.lom_specimen` and `SalesDWH.dbo.Isomers` that were excluded.

how do i get the counts of the excluded fields ?

here is the full query:

```
USE [SalesDWH]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[TurnAround]    Script Date: 07/10/2012 20:46:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO






ALTER VIEW [dbo].[TurnAround]
AS
SELECT     dbo.QuickLabDump.[Specimen ID], DATEPART(yyyy, dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered]) AS [Year Entered],
DATEPART(yyyy, dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed]) AS [year completed],

 CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered] AS DATE) 
                      AS DATETIME) + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Entered] AS TIME) AS [DateTime Entered], CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 
                      + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Completed] AS TIME) AS [DateTime Completed], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Practice Code] AS [QL Practuce Code], 
                      dbo.QLMLISMapping.[MLIS Practice ID], DATEPART(m, dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered]) AS [Month Entered], 
                      DATEPART(m, dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed]) AS [Month Completed],
                      ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, 
                      CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Entered] AS TIME), 
                      CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Completed] AS TIME)) AS FLOAT) / 60, 0) AS TAT, 
                      ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST('9:00AM' AS TIME), 


                      CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 
                      + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Completed] AS TIME)) AS float) / 60, 0) 

                      AS [Hours TurnAround Since 9AM], TAT9AMStateAdjusted=                   



                      ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 
                      + CAST('9:00AM' AS TIME),                                            
                      CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 
                      + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Completed] AS TIME)) AS float) / 60, 0)                         


                      +dbo.adjustedtime.timedifference
                      ,dbo.QuickLabDump.[Order Count], CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(D, - (1 * DATEPART(dw, dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered])) + 6,
                       dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered]), 1) AS [Week Ending]
FROM         dbo.QuickLabDump 
             INNER JOIN dbo.QLMLISMapping 
             ON dbo.QuickLabDump.[Practice Code] = dbo.QLMLISMapping.[Quicklab ID]
             left outer join dbo.AccountState
             on dbo.QuickLabDump.[Practice Code]=dbo.AccountState.[Account]
             left outer join dbo.AdjustedTime 
             ON dbo.AccountState.[state]=dbo.adjustedtime.[state]

             left outer join hermes.lom.dbo.lom_specimen Lom
              on QuickLabDump.[specimen id] = lom.specimen
              LEFT outer join SalesDWH.dbo.Isomers Isomers
              on QuickLabDump.[specimen id] = Isomers.[accession id]



WHERE     lom.specimen is null
              and isomers.[accession id] is null

              and (dbo.QuickLabDump.[Practice Code] NOT LIKE 'test%') 
              AND (dbo.QuickLabDump.[Specimen ID] NOT LIKE 'of%') 
              AND (dbo.QuickLabDump.Outcome <> 'rejected')
GROUP BY dbo.QuickLabDump.[Specimen ID], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Entered], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed], 
                      dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Completed], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Practice Name], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Practice Code], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Order Count], 
                      dbo.QLMLISMapping.[MLIS Practice ID],dbo.adjustedtime.timedifference
HAVING      (dbo.QuickLabDump.[Order Count] = MAX(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Order Count])) OR
                      (dbo.QuickLabDump.[Order Count] IS NULL)






GO
```

Comment: what columns are you selecting?

Comment: im not sure how that could help but ive included the entire query

Comment: You can do it with a group by, but with all those columns...

Comment: Do you want a total count of the rows excluded or a count for each table that rows were excluded from?

Comment: @ZaneBien count for each table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT      ...,
            (
              SELECT COUNt(*) FROM hermes.lom.dbo.lom_specimen WHERE specimen = lom.specimen
             ) AS ColCount

FROM         dbo.QuickLabDump    
             left outer join hermes.lom.dbo.lom_specimen Lom   
              on QuickLabDump.[specimen id] = lom.specimen   
              LEFT outer join SalesDWH.dbo.Isomers Isomers   
              on QuickLabDump.[specimen id] = Isomers.[accession id]   
WHERE     lom.specimen is null   
              and isomers.[accession id] is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Running the same query without the WHERE clause and using FULL OUTER JOINs would give you all the rows in the selectable universe.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer can you please elaborate on this?